# visual studio not letting me add a VB.Net file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have an example web solution that I downloaded and when I try Add New Item (e.g. page, web control, etc.), only C# is present as a language option.  In other solutions I use, I see C# and VB.  How can I add a new VB item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current project is a C# project, you will only be able to add C# items to an existing project.

You should be able to add a new project to the solution, set it to a VB.Net project, then add VB items to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this in a web project, you might be able to achieve this like DotNetNuke does it. Check out [this post](http://www.revindex.com/Blogs/tabid/65/EntryID/4/Default.aspx) as to what files have to go in what folder (specifically App_Code) as well as changes to your web.config file. I do have to admit that other than DNN, I've never tried to do this in a regular web project.